# Installing Ubuntu 21.10 on Windows 11

Tags: usb-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu 21.10 using Windows 11 and can't do it because of errors. First, I tried to install it using Virtual Box and go a green screen that showed a system exception error in one of VB's files. Come to find out, Virtual Box won't support Windows 11 until version 7 which is not out yet. Next, I tried to install it using a USB stick, but when I tried to use the boot drive writer (USBIMAGER) I got another green screen that showed a Kernel Mode error. I am wondering if this has something to do with the new tighter security in Windows 11. Since this is the first time I have ever used Linux, I am really at a loss. Does anyone have experience installing 21.10 on Windows 11 and do you have any suggestions? Thanks in advance, Mike.

Comment: Are you trying to install in dual boot? or just want ti use as a virtual machine?

Comment: Your intent of "*installing 21.10 on Windows 11*" does not seem to match your actions so far. You can 1) Destroy Windows and overwrite with Ubuntu. Or you can 2) Run Ubuntu in a VM using WSL (or VirtualBox soon) so you can use both OS simultaneously. Or you can 3) Dual-boot, so either can tun on bare metal (but not simultaneously). Your Question should explain which of those install modes you really want.

Comment: To answer your question, I would prefer using the virtual machine, but I could do the dual boot option. Since this is my first try of Linux, I definitely don't want to get rid of Windows right now. Do you have to using the Windows 11 WSL to install it? Thanks for your reply.